# Should I create a layout file for each card view I have?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am creating an app that shows business card like images of discounts for businesses around my state.

I got a warning saying:

> restaurants_mugshots_grill_and_bar_card <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>: Layout has too many views

The layout file I have looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFC107"
        android:padding="40dp"
        tools:context=".RestaurantsActivity">

        <!-- 306 BBQ-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/restaurants__306_BBQ_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/restaurants__306_BBQ"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/restaurants_306_bbq_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/activity_alabama_music_hall_of_fame_card"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/restaurants__306_BBQ_Facebook"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/r_306bbqFB"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/restaurants__306_BBQ_Instagram"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/r_306bbqIG"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/restaurants__306_BBQ_Website"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/r_306bbqWeb"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/restaurants__306_BBQ_Directions"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/r_306bbqDir"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Big Bad Breakfast-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/restaurants_big_bad_breakfast_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/restaurants__306_BBQ_card"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/restaurants_big_bad_breakfast"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/restaurants_big_bad_breakfast_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/activity_alabama_music_hall_of_fame_card"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <LinearLayout
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/restaurants_big_bad_breakfast_facebook"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/rbbbFB"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/restaurants_big_bad_breakfast_Instagram"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/rbbbIG"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/restaurants_big_bad_breakfast_Website"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/rbbbWeb"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/restaurants_big_bad_breakfast_Directions"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/rbbbDir"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                tools:ignore="VisualLintButtonSize" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

As of right now I have 12 of those card views in the one XML layout, and I will be adding around 9 more at the moment, and much more in the future.

Would it be more beneficial to just create a layout.xml file for each one?

and if that is the case, is there a way I can put them inside a folder? I am doing this for many different businesses not just restaurants, restaurants just have the most. I do not to see 200 different XML files in my project navigator if I do not have to, and I would like to be able to organize them by business category, i.e. activities, health and beauty, restaurants, services etc...

I have been putting them all in one file as of right now and it works, I just do not want to deal with any warnings or errors in the future.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a single layout template for each business type and just reuse them? If you're planning on showing a lot of items in your app I highly suggest looking into the RecyclerView component rather than just putting all items in ScrollView. This will help your app perform better when the user scrolls the list.

Comment: This might be the way I go. I am pretty new to android development, and this project I was given was created back in 2015 I believe so it is very old code with little to no comments. I am about to rewrite my entire project based on that and see how it will look. Thank you!